# Multiple initStatements in local.xml

Tags: xml, configuration, local.xml

I have a question regarding the `local.xml` (config) file in `app/etc/.` How is it possible to add multiple initStatements?

Currently it looks like this:

```
<initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
```

Now I also want to add this:

```
 <initStatements><![CDATA[SET lock_wait_timeout=120]]></initStatements>
```

Obviously, I can't just add this line, so there must be a way to append the `"SET lock_wait_timeout=120"` to `"SET NAMES utf8"`. But now, does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the semicolon `;` as a default separator,  your initStatement would look like:

```
<initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8; SET lock_wait_timeout=120;]]></initStatements>
```

alternative: consider putting the corresponding setting in `/etc/my.cnf`